# Excel VBA - Seems Something Wrong with ws Naming

Tags: vba, excel

I am so desperate I keep running into VBA error 1004 for the below code:

```
  Sub GetRawPrices()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim wq As QueryTable
  Dim url As String
  Dim wb0 As Workbook
  Set wb0 = ThisWorkbook
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 2 To wb0.Worksheets("Consolidation").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row Step 1
  Set wb = Workbooks.Add
  wb.SaveAs Filename:="G:\2015July\Desktop2\HORIZONTAL\" & wb0.Worksheets("Consolidation").Cells(i, 1).Value & ".xlsx"
  url = _
    "TEXT;" & _
    "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?" & _
    "s=" & _
    wb0.Worksheets("Consolidation").Cells(i, 1).Value & _
    "&" & _
    "a=01&" & _
    "b=01&" & _
    "c=2015&" & _
    "d=03&" & _
    "e=12&" & _
    "f=2017&" & _
    "g=d&" & _
    "ignore=.csv"
  Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheet3)
  ws.Name = "YAHOO_DATA"
  Set wq = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:=url, _
    Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
  wq.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
  wq.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
  wq.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  wb.Close savechanges:=True
  Next i

End Sub
```

It looks like to me there is something wrong with the two lines below, because I can create and save the wb properly, and I only run into error 1004 without creating the new worksheet ws "YAHOO_DATA".

```
  Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheet3)
  ws.Name = "YAHOO_DATA"
```

But what can be wrong? I have another Excel file that runs the almost exact same code and it works well...

I would be grateful if anyone can solve this problem for me... It's been 2 hours since I have stared at this code already! Thanks!

Bosco

Comment: What do you see when you use the debugger to step through the code? When that error occurs, Excel tells you exactly which line is causing it, so you shouldn't have to be guessing.

Comment: Also, have you searched here for the exact error message you're getting? This question has been asked (and answered) many times here before; surely one of the existing answers would have been helpful.

Comment: Hello Ken, The error is "Run-time error "1004": Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: but it has not mentioned the line where the error occur as you spoke...

Comment: Do you have a sheet with a codename of `Sheet3` in the newly created workbook?

Comment: hello YowE3K yes i do, Sheet1 Sheet2 Sheet3 come as default after opening new Excel file in my case

Comment: And which of the two lines is highlighted when you click on "Debug" on the error dialog?

Comment: i dont have a debug button on the error dialog... it just says run time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error, then i can either click "OK" or "Help", no debug button...?

Comment: Place a `MsgBox "1:" & ws.Name` between the two lines you are talking about, and a `MsgBox "2:" & ws.Name` after the second line.  Then run the code again.  Depending on which `MsgBox` displays we might be able to isolate the error.

Comment: Hello YowE3K, just added both msgbox and run again, run time error 1004 show up before either display box shows.

Comment: can it be somehow the wb and ws references are not well-defined by me? so that after open file, save file etc, VBA then mix up my references somehow??

Comment: Yes, I know what the error is, and I asked **if you searched this site for it**. I've also asked you to step through the code in the debugger. And yes, Excel tells you **exactly** where the error happens; I know that because I've experienced it myself. When there's an error in VBA code, Excel stops at the line where the error happened. What line is it stopping at?

Comment: The `Connection` argument for `QueryTables.Add` should be a Variant. In your code `Url` is dimensioned as String. Change that `Dim` statement and try again.

Comment: Hello Ken White, sorry slightly new to VBA this is the first time I use the debug function, i used debug and "step into", it stops at this line: "  Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheet3)", what do you think?

Comment: and Ken White I did search through this site and see lots of 1004 error, but seems each 1004 error is different to me...

Comment: Yes - the 1004 error is a very generic message - it basically means "some object doesn't like something that is being done".  Without knowing the specific line it is crashing on, it could mean anything.

Comment: Prior to the line causing an error, place a line saying `For Each ws In wb.Worksheets: MsgBox ws.CodeName & "|" & ws.Name : Next` (or enter that into the Immediate Window if the code is still in "break" mode, and you can find the immediate window)

Comment: hello YowE3K, i did what you say, 3 message boxes show up, with messages Sheet1|Sheet1, Sheet2|Sheet2, Sheet3|Sheet3 respectively, then the run-time error 1004 box again. What does that mean then?

Comment: Have you tried putting quotation marks on the sheet name `Sheet3`, like `Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:="Sheet3")`?

Comment: hello Rowen, tried just now, still error!

Comment: Try  `Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worsheets("Sheet3"))`

Comment: Typo in @A.S.H comment - should be `Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets("Sheet3"))`

Comment: Holy Lord! A.S.H. method works! but what exactly is the difference!?

Comment: @BoscoTsin The difference is the use of *explicit* references. `Worksheets("Sheet3")` <=> `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")`, if the `ActiveWorkbook` is not `wb` you get into trouble. It's always better to use explicit references.

Answer (score 3):

Change the following line

```
Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheet3)
```

to

```
Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
```

In some MS Excel versions, new workbooks don't have 3 new sheets created.